# How to compile an app on Xcode without developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, development, code-signing

as you know from Xcode 7 and onwards it's possible to compile an app for your device.

Yesterday I tried to compile Kodi on Xcode 7. It says it's possible to compile with Xcode 7 without any developer account in the readme too..

Here is the problem though. I previously had a developer account. Now it's expired.

So when I open up the Xcode I saw that my account is already there with description "Free"..

[image: XCode 7 Accounts screen]

When I click View Details.. though:

[image: View Details..]

So, there is a iOS developer certificate. But no provision profile. And when I try to compile it says "No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found."

It's not possible to fix this error too.. Even when I click Fix Issue in General tab, it says "An App with identifier "org.xbmc.kodi-ios" is not available. Please enter a different string."

How could I create a provisioning profile for this app? Actually for all apps with "*" ?

Is it possible that I could start over this process somehow?!? It may be because I had a developer account before ( and I still have as a member but that's not active )

How could I self sign this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the identifier to something unique to you, like "net.plato.kodi-ios" and then try having Xcode fix the issue.

I eventually got Kodi to compile on my own after tweaking some of the provisioning settings, but I have active developer profiles and haven't ever done anything with the free account.

There have been limits on the number of free apps you can sign. See this link to stack overflow if you run into errors.

- [Xcode Error: Unable to install app (Error Code: Code: -402620383)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392156/xcode-error-unable-to-install-app-error-code-code-402620383)

Comment: That did the work. Weird that we cannot use the original name. It is to prevent overwriting on original app, I guess. Thanks again.