# Apple dev license expired - Renew(paying) or else?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

My paid apple dev license expired a year ago. In the meanwhile Xcode 7 came out with the option of testing locally on iOS devices without the need of a paid license.

I am now developing a Unity game that targets iOS devices. I build for iOS and open the Xcode project that returns this error:

> No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e.
>   certificate and private key pair) were found.

I then suppose I would need to create certificates and related stuff, but if I access the apple dev portal I am presented with this:

[image]

What should I do at this stage to be able to test o local devices without paying?

Comment: I've edited out the side question - renewing membership means you pay for another year of Apple-signed certificates. When you follow http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226338/how-to-compile-an-app-on-xcode-without-developer-account - do you see free listed for your Apple ID? Does changing the bundle of the app that was signed help to get you a free certificate?

Comment: I see free listed on my apple id. I changed the bundle. I really don't know how to test it in my iPhone now though....

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know this one.. but it depends on the features you want to test!

For some features you are required to have an Apple ID like Apple Pay.

[Supported capabilities for developing on your device](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1)