# Xcode Error: Unable to install app (Error Code: Code: -402620383)

Tags: iphone, applications, xcode, development

I am using my free Apple developer account (Apple ID) for learning to develop iOS apps with Xcode. My iOS version is 13.5 and I am running Xcode 11.5 on Mac Catalina version 10.15.4.

I created a simple app that prints some text on the screen on my iPhone X, and when I tried to run the app, Xcode returned an error:

> "Unable to install app", error code: -402620383.

When I clicked for more details, I got a more detailed description of the error:

> "The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached."

After much search on the Internet, I tried the following fixes and none of these worked:

1. Creating a new Apple ID and link that to Xcode.
2. Unpaired my iPhone X/deleted the provisioning profiles in windows/devices in Xcode.
3. Checked in the windows/devices and simulators and there were no apps installed.

The interesting thing is that I tried running the app on my wife's iPhone X (running iOS 13.5 as well) and it worked. Digging a little deeper, I noticed device management under settings/general is missing in my iPhone but present in my wife's iPhone. The profile of the app I was trying to install in device management. Maybe that is the cause of the problem. I really don't know what to do and would appreciate help on this, thanks!

Comment: What worked for me was deleting and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: @Todd That's not the approach to take in my opinion. It isn't reasonable to reinstall Xcode entirely just to switch to a different developer account/device.

Comment: Do you have other apps that are already installed using this method? Or does this happen the first time you try?

Comment: @Tom Harrington  I had no previously installed apps, it's my first time testing the app on my iPhone. What I don't understand is the app worked fine on my wife's iPhone running the same version of iOS but it didn't work on my phone.

Comment: In that case I'm inclined to blame Xcode flakiness, which calls for voodoo fixes. Quit/relaunch Xcode, disconnect/reconnect phone, reboot Mac and phone, and then see what happens. It's a lot of nonsense but it's often what's needed.

Comment: I found the solution. It seems that the free developer account is counting 'offloaded' apps toward three apps limit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode/61978102#61978102

Answer (score 1):

It is a very hot issue with the new update of Catalina.
To be very precise the issue is with the **manually signing** of the provisioning profile. If you check **Automatically manage signing** it works.

Answer (score 1):

Free developers, head to stack overflow for instructions how to delete your old apps to get back under the limit.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode/

Or if your pay for a dev subscription, this limit is eased and you can work work developer support if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the DerivedData folder in Terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

If it still doesn't work, reinstall the Xcode (it's an issue in Catalina).