# Can I compile and locally run SimpleFirewall example app without enrolling with apple developer program?

Tags: macos, network, security, development, firewall

I was curious about writing my own simple application firewall.
After going through several tutorials I've downloaded SimpleFirewall example app available at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/filtering_network_traffic

Compilation fails with the following error message:

`Personal development teams, including 'John Doe', do not support the System Extension and Network Extensions capabilities.`

Is there a way not to pay 100 bucks a year to be able to compile an application firewall that I'm planning to use only on my local macOS machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile an app on Xcode without developer account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226338/how-to-compile-an-app-on-xcode-without-developer-account)

Answer (score 2):

There’s three problems here.

1. you can [compile code without a paid / free account from Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226338/how-to-compile-an-app-on-xcode-without-developer-account) and optionally use or avoid Xcode and the entitlements request procedure that Xcode is trying to request on your behalf.
2. you can [disable system protection so that you can run code that normally requires these entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63486231/475228) for store distribution and automatic sandboxing
3. Apple has a [fee waiver](https://developer.apple.com/support/membership-fee-waiver/) that might reduce your cost for an [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).

The steps to accomplish 2 vary per release of macOS. The steps for 1 are likely better suited for code level assistance available on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Network%20extensions&searchOn=3)

Comment: okay, it seems there is some helpful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476574/is-there-a-way-to-add-the-network-extensions-capability-to-a-macos-app-without-j